# Реально ли посчитать определитель матрицы при помощи статических двумерных массивов с++

Tags: c++

Университетские лабораторные были составлены садистами.
Необходимо вычислить обратную матрицу. Для этого понятное дело нужно постоянно вычислять определители и миноры.
Внимание! Запрещены динамические массивы, итераторы, контейнеры, любые библиотеки для обработки матриц, указатели, операторы new, delete.
И вот меня терзают сомнения, насчет реальности выполнения сиё чуда.
Может у кого есть хотя бы алгоритм как мы можем на статических массивах вычислять миноры и т.д.

Comment: А чем не нравится метод Гаусса? Все в пределах одной матрицы... Через определители и миноры — это же O(n!), насколько я помню. Ну, а если так уж нужно - то используйте статические матрицы заведомо большего размера, работая только с их частью.

Comment: огромное спасибо за напоминании о методе гаусса. Просто огромнейшее

Comment: Может, надо удалить этот вопрос?